# Filtering JSON snapshot using textfield text

Tags: flutter

I have created a listView populated from a JSON String received from a web service.
I would like to filter the data depending on a search string inserted into a textField widget.

The json string is received in this future:

```
future: fetchPacientes(value)
```

How should I get the filtered values from the snapShot depending on the string inserted in the textField?

```
body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'Patients'.tr().toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.black45),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            // in the build method above list
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                hintText: 'Filter by name or NHC',
              ),
              onChanged: (string) {
                print("filtering string->:"+ string);

              },
            ),

            Expanded(
              child: Consumer(
                builder: (context, watch, child) {
                  var value = watch(clinicaIdStateProvider).state;

                  return Container(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: fetchPacientes(value),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                         
                          return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                              Paciente paciente = snapshot.data[index];
                              return new GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print("paciente seleccionada nbre: " +
                                      '${paciente.nombre_completo}');
                                },
                                child: new Card(

                                  elevation: 6,
                                  child: new Container(

                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "${paciente.apellidos}" +
                                                      ", " +
                                                      "${paciente.nombre_completo}",
                                                  style:
                                                      TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        color:
                                                            AppColors.azulCapenergy,
                                                        border: Border.all(
                                                          color: AppColors
                                                              .azulCapenergy,
                                                        ),
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius.all(
                                                                Radius.circular(
                                                                    20))),
                                                    child: Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        "NHC: ${paciente.NHC}",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: AppColors
                                                                .blancoCapenergy,
                                                            fontSize: 16),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),

                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(height: 3,),
                                                  FlatButton(
                                                    onPressed: (){
                                                      print("boton agenda pulsado de ${paciente.nombre_completo}");
                                                    },
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          color:
                                                          Colors.transparent,
                                                          border: Border.all(
                                                            color: AppColors
                                                                .azulCapenergy,
                                                          ),
                                                          borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.all(
                                                              Radius.circular(
                                                                  15))),
                                                      child: Padding(
                                                        padding:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                        child: Image.network(
                                                          'https://...iconos_app/agenda.png',
                                                          height: 25,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),

                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),

                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        }

                        return Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/vacio.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `TextEditingController` and add it to textField controller, then you have access to textField text anywhere you want.

you can use it to write a filter method for snapshot.data or create a map if there is limited numbers of states

sample

```
 final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

@override
  void initState() {
    _controller.addListener(_filterList);
    super.initState();
  }

body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'Patients'.tr().toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.black45),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            // in the build method above list
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                hintText: 'Filter by name or NHC',
              ),
              onChanged: (string) {
                print("filtering string->:"+ string);

              },
            ),

            Expanded(
              child: Consumer(
                builder: (context, watch, child) {
                  var value = watch(clinicaIdStateProvider).state;

                  return Container(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: fetchPacientes(value),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                         
                          return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                              Paciente paciente = snapshot.data[index];
                              return new GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print("paciente seleccionada nbre: " +
                                      '${paciente.nombre_completo}');
                                },
                                child: new Card(

                                  elevation: 6,
                                  child: new Container(

                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "${paciente.apellidos}" +
                                                      ", " +
                                                      "${paciente.nombre_completo}",
                                                  style:
                                                      TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        color:
                                                            AppColors.azulCapenergy,
                                                        border: Border.all(
                                                          color: AppColors
                                                              .azulCapenergy,
                                                        ),
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius.all(
                                                                Radius.circular(
                                                                    20))),
                                                    child: Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        "NHC: ${paciente.NHC}",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: AppColors
                                                                .blancoCapenergy,
                                                            fontSize: 16),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),

                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(height: 3,),
                                                  FlatButton(
                                                    onPressed: (){
                                                      print("boton agenda pulsado de ${paciente.nombre_completo}");
                                                    },
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          color:
                                                          Colors.transparent,
                                                          border: Border.all(
                                                            color: AppColors
                                                                .azulCapenergy,
                                                          ),
                                                          borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.all(
                                                              Radius.circular(
                                                                  15))),
                                                      child: Padding(
                                                        padding:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                        child: Image.network(
                                                          'https://...iconos_app/agenda.png',
                                                          height: 25,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),

                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),

                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        }

                        return Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/vacio.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thank yoy @DNS, but this is just my question, how to write the filter method for the snapshot using the textField  to get the search string

Comment: this means your question is body of _filterList in my code, am I right?

Comment: I am not able to find _filterList in your code?

Comment: inside initState(), line 4

Comment: Yes, but I mean where are you declaring _filterList?

Comment: I'm not yet :D, can you fill me with an example of your json data and the textfield string? textfiled is gonna be the key value of json or what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229814/discussion-between-mvasco-and-dns).